# Time Series Subsetting by Integers

Tags: r, window, time-series, subset

I've seen a lot of posts in regards to subsetting time series through specific date requirements, but I can not figure out how to subset based on integers. Consider:

```
# create dummy data
data <- ts(seq_len(96), start=c(2009,1), f=12)
# create training data
training.set <- ts(data[1:(length(data)-8)], start=c(2009,1), frequency=12)

# I want to remove the last 8 values (or any integer) and use that as a test set while retaining the correct dates
test.set <- ts(data[(length(data)-8+1):length(data)])
test.set # start/end aren't retained for the test set

Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 8 
Frequency = 1 
[1] 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96
```

I know I can specify the new start/end dates on the test set explicitly, but that won't work for my use. I'm trying to find a way to automatically do that so a function I'm writing can handle any dates based on the input time series and subset both training and test sets (based on any integer < length of the input series).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you cannot have arbitrary subsetting because `"ts"` class can only represent regularly spaced series; however,  you can subset an interval.

**1) base**  Here is a base solution which subsets time and then uses that as input to `window`.  (Had the interval not ended at the end of the series we would have had to use `end=` as well.)

```
window(data, start = tail(time(data), 8)[1])
```

giving:

```
     May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2016  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96
```

**2) zoo** We can work directly with the time series if we first convert to zoo.  After conversion take the subset and convert back (or omit the `as.ts` leaving it as a zoo object and work with that):

```
library(zoo)

as.ts(tail(as.zoo(data), 8))
```

**2a)**  Here is a variation of (2):

```
as.ts(as.zoo(data)[seq(to = length(data), length = 8)])
```

(2) and (2a) give the same answer as (1).

Comment: This worked great. I can also use the zoo version to subset the training data easier. Much appreciated. Accepting